# How to add user into database for BPM Suite

Tags: jboss-eap-7, redhat-bpm

I configure store user into database (SQL Server) on bpm suite v6.4.0. How to insert user into database (don't insert by manual), i want know bpm suite v6.4.0 have library support for this  doesn't. I don't find document mention this problem.
Thanks for any idea or your help

Comment: It is not possible because KIE Will manage all the database operation.So it is not possible to make any CRUID operation through KIE workbench. you can do everything using workitemhandler s. work item s are pieces of pure java code that you could insert in service tasks. for more detail follow http://fxapps.blogspot.com/2015/04/creating-custom-work-item-handler-in.html blog

See: https://docs.jboss.org/jbpm/v3.3/userguide/ch07.html and https://docs.jboss.org/jbpm/v3/userguide/thejbpmdatabase.html

Answer (score 0):

Authentication/authorization is delegated to an underlying security configuration.  I assume you are configuring your security domain to retrieve login information from database?  jBPM has some basic user and group mgmt UI (for creating users / groups etc.) that will push these changes to the underlying service.  We do have an adapter for RH-SSO so I would recommend to configure your app server to delegate authentication/authorization to RH-SSO, which could be configured to use a database for storing users.